# Does the ternary operator combined with C-style upcasting of pointers invoke undefined behavior in this instance?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, conditional-operator, upcasting

Motivating background:  While trying to debug a hard-to-reproduce fault-condition in my software, I came across some questionable pointer-casting code that was written by a naive junior developer (okay, I admit it, it was me, 10 years ago) that I suspect might be the underlying cause of the fault.

I rewrote the code to use proper `static_cast<>` calls instead, and I haven't seen the fault condition occur since the rewrite, but that doesn't necessarily mean anything given that the fault rarely occurred anyway; I could just be "getting lucky" so far.

My question is:  does the C-style up-casting of pointers performed inside `main()` in the code below invoke undefined behavior?  Or is it just ugly, but nevertheless well-formed from a language-lawyer perspective?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

class BaseClass
{
public:
   BaseClass() {}
   virtual ~BaseClass() {}

   virtual void Foo() {printf("BaseClass::Foo() called\n");}
};

class SubClassA : public BaseClass
{
public:
   SubClassA() {}

   virtual void Foo() {printf("SubClassA::Foo() called\n");}
};

class SubClassB : public BaseClass
{
public:
   SubClassB() {}

   virtual void Foo() {printf("SubClassB::Foo() called\n");}
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   SubClassA a;
   SubClassB b;

   // Warning:  questionable C-style casting follows...
   BaseClass * p = (rand()%2) ? ((BaseClass*)(&a)) : ((BaseClass*)(&b));
   p->Foo();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the ternary operator in combination with any casting gives any kind of undesirable result, I bet a nice dinner (restaurant is my pick) that at the core of the problem is NOT the ternary operator. It is always the casting (or something you missed altogether).

Comment: If the C-style upcasting is legal to begin with, I can't see a reason why it would become undefined when put into the conditional operator.

Comment: The type of a conditional operator only becomes confusing when the true and false subexpressions are different types -- a common type has to be determined for the whole expression. But that's not an issue here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cast is completely legal.  From [[expr.cast]/4.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cast#4.6)

> a pointer to an object of derived class type or an lvalue or rvalue of derived class type may be explicitly converted to a pointer or reference to an unambiguous base class type, respectively;